# Track Nodejs server progress on client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, file-upload

I have a server in nodejs running where I upload a large data file. I'm using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) on the client to do this, which helps me track the upload progress through a set of callback functions.

But when the upload is complete, the server starts working with the data (converting format and uploading to user specified database). I would like to track this progress as well in the same kind of manner as the upload, starting another progress bar.

What is the correct way to do this? Going through the internet, I have understood that sockets might be the way to go. Does that make my angular-file-upload obsolete, or is there another way to do this? Do I set up a new connection when the upload is complete, or do I utilize the upload connection, and return progress information to the client?

Socket.io does have a set of good tutorials on how to setup a chat sending messages to clients, but that does not really cover my a bit more complex situation.

Any pointers in the right directions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get realtime status of progress, then as soon as the file upload is done, immediately you would have to open up a socket connection to get data about the progress of server side logic for which you would need a database which is being constantly updated with the progress happening.

But this is a pain to execute as you would have to use a db like redis for tracking progress in an efficient manner which would again increase the architecture of your project which in turn increases the maintenance efforts and even though there are some great tutorials for socket.io, my solution would be to use a realtime Backend like firebase or Back& (spelt backand) .

Once the file is uploaded your backend will keep posting to firebase the current process and the progress and your client side will be listening to these changes and any changes is automatically reflected in your UI thanks to angulars 2 way data binding.